# Firefox extension: how to fill an input text field

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, toolbar

I have a custom toolbar button created in accordance with the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Toolbars/Custom_toolbar_button). The javascript code for the button is the following:

```
CustomButton = {

1: function () {
  alert("Just testing") 
  },

}
```

And it works. When I click on this button, alert happens. I'm trying to make some changes, namely, fill input field on clicking this button, but this piece of code doesn't work:

```
CustomButton = {

1: function () {
  document.getElementById("loginUserName").value = "aaaa";  
  },

}
```

The element with Id "loginUserName" exists on the page. I can easily fill it with Selenium WebDriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("loginUserName")).sendKeys(User).
```

So my question is why it doesn't work in Firefox extension?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your toolbar button and the input field (assuming the latter is part of a web page) live in separate documents. But it's easy cross the boundary. Change your code to

```
gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById("loginUserName").value = "aaaa";
```